# Ansible sum int value to a registered value

Tags: math, ansible, sum

I need to sum an integer number to a registered value with ansible.. I tried with this but it doesn't works -->

```
---
- hosts: localhost
  gather_facts: false
  tasks:
    - name: Ricavo ultima linea /etc/passwd
      shell: tail -1 /etc/passwd
      register: lastuser
      ignore_errors: no

    - set_fact:
        uid: "{{ lastuser.stdout.split(':')[2] }}"
        gid: "{{ lastuser.stdout.split(':')[3] }}"
        newuid: "{{ uid|int + 5 }}"
        newgid: "{{ gid|int + 5 }}"
    - debug:
        msg: "UID is {{ uid }} GID is {{ gid }}"
    - debug:
        msg: "NEW UID is {{ newuid }} GID is {{ newgid }}"
```

but i get -->

```
fatal: [localhost]: FAILED! => {"msg": "The task includes an option with an undefined variable. The error was: 'uid' is undefined\n\nThe error appears to have been in '/tmp/test_ansible/get_lastuser.yaml': line 10, column 7, but may\nbe elsewhere in the file depending on the exact syntax problem.\n\nThe offending line appears to be:\n\n\n    - set_fact:\n      ^ here\n"}
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the issue is that the `uid` and `gid` variables are not available till the completion of `set_fact` task. It should work if you split the `set_fact` tasks. Something like below:

```yaml
    - set_fact:
        uid: "{{ lastuser.stdout.split(':')[2] }}"
        gid: "{{ lastuser.stdout.split(':')[3] }}"

    - set_fact:
        newuid: "{{ uid|int + 5 }}"
        newgid: "{{ gid|int + 5 }}"

    - debug:
        msg:
        - "UID is {{ uid }} GID is {{ gid }}"
        - "NEW UID is {{ newuid }} GID is {{ newgid }}"
```